# How to draw a cylinder using ArrowHelper in three.js

Tags: angular, three.js

I am trying to create a cylinder to a ArrowHelper

```
     var dir = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 1, 0 );
              dir.normalize();
              var origin = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 1, 0 );
              var length = 100;
              var hex = 0x00ff00;
              var lengthPlane = 5;
              var headLength = 10;
              var headWidth = 10;
              var arrowHelperY = new THREE.ArrowHelper( dir, origin, length, hex, headLength, headWidth );

   var geometry = new THREE.CylinderBufferGeometry( 5, 5, 100, 100 );
              var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0x0000FF} );
              var cylinder = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
              arrowHelperY.add( cylinder );
              this.SceneAxes.add( arrowHelperY );
```

Result:

[image]

Code: To create y axis using arrowhelper and cylinder

Please help me to do

Comment: Have you tried the code [in the cylinder geometry documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/CylinderBufferGeometry)? It shows you how to do it right there.

Comment: @Marquizzo, yes. I tried, but i am not getting how to add to Arrowhelper..i am completely beginner..

Comment: How about `arrowHelper.add(cylinder);`?

Comment: @Marquizzo i added result

Comment: now you have to update its position and rotation. I strongly recommend you visit [this page with useful links to beginner tutorials](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Useful-links) There are lots of articles to the fundamentals of Three.js in there.